# Delete with join and condition (3 tables) - MySQL

Tags: mysql, delete

Need some assistance on MySQL delete using join with condition (3 tables).

```
snote (child table)
--------
snote_id
bnote_id

bnote (parent table of snote)
------
bnote_id
note_id

note (parent table of bnote)
----
note_id
```

Want to delete all snote records with bnote_id=10 and note_id=5

Answer (score 2):

Able to find the answer in another post... Sorry for raising this as duplicate

```
DELETE `stn` FROM `snote` AS `stn` 
LEFT JOIN `bnote` AS `ban` ON `ban`.`bnote_id`=`stn`.`bnote_id` 
WHERE `ban`.`note_id`='5' AND `stn`.`bnote_id` = '10'
```

Comment: Use `INNER` join, not `LEFT`. It won't make any difference for this query but the intention will be more visible.